# create a "Best-effort" pod and its oom score not 1000 but -999

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Create a deployment as below:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    owt: hello
    pdl: com
    app: world
    idc: xg
    add: parameters-48
  name: parameters-48
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: parameters-48
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mofang-web
        image: registry.cc.com/online/mofang:stable
      nodeSelector:
        node:cc
```

Login to node found the container's pid, then check its oom score:

```
cat /proc/21606/oom_adj
-16
cat /proc/21606/oom_score
0
cat /proc/21606/oom_score_adj
-999
```

According user guide page: https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/resource-qos.md, this pod should be a "Best-effort" pod, but its OOM_SCORE_ADJ not 1000 but -999.
By the way -999 means won't be oom killed.

Comment: Seems "oom score" in kubernetes is different with linux system "oom score"? If yes, how can I get the pod's current "oom score"?

Comment: Your perception might be right when using Kubernetes with Docker the OOM is not used as you've assumed as you'll see in the source of [pkg/kubelet/qos/policy.go](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/7028abc5fcb41e7975b98f0900d5765afc48f464/pkg/kubelet/qos/policy.go) and [pkg/kubelet/cm/container_manager_linux.go#L371](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/2541c16692c7777b0aeda8124f7895855b1b9232/pkg/kubelet/cm/container_manager_linux.go#L371) you might want to file an [issue on Github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/)

Comment: issuse: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/40990

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/40990), it's maybe worth to summarize how to find the correct container pid / proc for a pod:

Run some application:

```
$ kubectl run bootcamp --image=docker.io/jocatalin/kubernetes-bootcamp:v1
```

Find the containerID:

```
$ kubectl get pods --output=jsonpath='{.items[*].status.containerStatuses[*].containerID}'
docker://59f127d641cef9475309cbf4b5fc2e4a65f3e52a0e08112dccbc2c144a0e366f
```

Find the related host / node:

```
$ kubectl get pods --output=jsonpath='{.items[*].status.hostIP}'                          
192.168.99.100
```

Both could also be found with:

```
$ kubectl describe pod <podID>
```

Connect to the node via SSH, then run:

```
$ docker inspect 59f127d641cef9475309cbf4b5fc2e4a65f3e52a0e08112dccbc2c144a0e366f | grep Pid\":
"Pid": 18052,
$ cat /proc/18052/oom_*         
15
1000
1000
```

Hope this helps someone else at some point